# Creating an Observable around sets of continously changing depended observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

**The code snippet below is my attempt at creating the following functionality:**

- Create an observable sequence that subscribes to a collection of subjects
- When one of the subjects in the collection produces a value, the sequence ends, invokes a method that returns a new set of subjects and restarts at 1.
- When the subscription to the outer observable gets disposed the whole thing stops

**Questions about my implementation:**

- Why does it work using *subjectsSub.SelectMany(x => x).Merge()* but not using *subjectsSub.Merge()*? (I would have expected the latter approach to work)
- Is there a simpler, more elegant solution to this in the vast arsenal of Rx Functionality?

**Update**: This sample was actually back-ported from RxJS-Typescript to reach a broader audience with this question. The fact that the original runs in a single-threaded browser environment using Javascript should make it clearer why this "observable capturing" may work (it does and without dirty hacks like messing with RxJs internals).

---

```
    class Program
    {
      private static readonly Queue<IObservable<Unit>[]> observableDependencies = new Queue<IObservable<Unit>[]>();

      private static IObservable<Unit>[] EvaluateExpressionAndCaptureTouchedObservables(Func<object> expression)
      {
        // wire some traps for capturing any observables "touched" by expression
        expression();

        // return observables touched by expression (not in this example of course)
        if (observableDependencies.Count > 0)
          return observableDependencies.Dequeue();

        return new[] {Observable.Never<Unit>()}; // keep going
      }

      private static IObservable<Unit> CreateObservable(
Subject<IObservable<Unit>[]> capturedObservables, Stopwatch sw)
      {
        return Observable.Create<Unit>(observer =>
        {
          var isComplete = new Subject<Unit>();
          var isAborted = false;

          var disp = Scheduler.Default.Schedule(self =>
          {
            Console.WriteLine("** Next iteration at {0}", sw.Elapsed);

            capturedObservables.SelectMany(x => x).Merge().TakeUntil(isComplete).Subscribe(x =>
            {
              observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);

              // self-destruct
              isComplete.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            },
            () =>
            {
              Console.WriteLine("completed");

              if (!isAborted)
                self();
            });

            capturedObservables.OnNext(EvaluateExpressionAndCaptureTouchedObservables());
          });

          return new CompositeDisposable(Disposable.Create(() =>
          {
            isAborted = true;

            // self-destruct
            isComplete.OnNext(Unit.Default);
          }), disp);
        });
      }

      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        observableDependencies.Enqueue(new[]
        {
          Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Select(x => Unit.Default)
        });

        observableDependencies.Enqueue(new[]
        {
          Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Select(x => Unit.Default),
          Observable.Return(10).Select(x => Unit.Default)
        });

        observableDependencies.Enqueue(new[] {Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Select(x => Unit.Default)});

        var capturedObservables = new Subject<IObservable<Unit>[]>();
        var obs = CreateObservable(capturedObservables, sw);

        var disp = obs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("** fired at {0}", sw.Elapsed));
        Console.ReadLine();

        disp.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve? I'd like to know more about where this "collection of subjects" is coming from - that part is assumed in your question, but it's the part that seems the most unidiomatic to me, particularly the idea of a downstream observer triggering their regeneration. I feel that just addressing the code above would be a disservice as I can't think of a scenario where I would do this.

Comment: @JamesWorld I expect the use case is to provide a magic calculation method that does automatic capturing of observable dependencies and then subscribes to them so that the calculation can be re-run whenever a dependency changes.  See `Knockout` computed properties for a JavaScript example.  I've seen c# examples as well.  A very useful feature that hides the complexity of Rx at a slight performance cost.

Comment: OK I get what you've said... (I've used knockout/angular etc. bindings myself). The part I'm less clear on is why you need to throw away the subjects and get new ones instead of setting them up once and be done with it. Maybe that would be clear with an actual example...

Comment: @JamesWorld - during re-evaluation you "forget" the previous dependencies and just capture the new set (which often turns out to be the exact same ones you had last evaluation).

Comment: Example calculation: `result = a() ? b() : c();` would be a case where depedencies change during re-evaluation.

Comment: @JamesWorld You've nailed it James. The purpose of this functionality is to capture references to Knockout-Style properties backed by an RxJS observable and automatically re-run an expression compiled by a modified version of the angular expression parser when any captured property observables change.

Comment: OK cool. Makes sense for RxJS, sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, `SelectMany` is needed because you have a 3-level deep observable: Subject of Array of Observable.  `Merge` only flattens one level.  `SelectMany` is just short hand for `Select` + `Merge`.  So `SelectMany.Merge` is applying 2 flattening operators, which is what you need.

Second answer...it seems like you could just use `Merge` + `FirstOrDefault` + `Defer` + `Repeat` and not even use a subject:

```
var disp = Observable
    .Defer(() => EvaluateExpressionAndCaptureTouchedObservables()
        .Merge()
        .FirstOrDefault(Unit.Default))
    .Repeat()
    .Subscribe(...);
```

`Defer` runs the capture function each time it is subscribed

`Merge` to flatten the array of observables

`FirstOrDefault` ends the stream as soon as any of the observables produces a value.  If all of them complete without producing a value, then it produces a single `Unit.Default` that you can observe.

`Repeat` resubscribes whenever it ends (due to `FirstOrDefault`), which triggers another capture (due to `Defer`).

This is obviously trivial to convert back to TypeScript...

Comment: Is it possible that your example is missing the SelectMany operator?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold I'm sure it is possible.  I didn't try to compile it.  But based on your signature for `IObservable<Unit>[]EvaluateExpressionAndCaptureTouchedObservables` it should not be required since there is an overload of `Merge` for `IEnumerable<IObservable<Unit>>`

Answer (score 0):

The more or less final version CreateObservable inspired by Brandon's suggestion. Which goes to show that 99% of the time you think you have to resort to scheduling stuff, you're doing it wrong™

```
private static IObservable<Unit> CreateObservable()
{
  return Observable.Create<Unit>(observer =>
  {
    var innerDisp = Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
      return Observable.Merge(
        EvaluateExpressionAndCaptureTouchedObservables(() => false))
      .Take(1);  // done when any observable produces a value
    })
    .Repeat()
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
      observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    });

    return innerDisp;
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `Buffer().Where()` just to throttle evaluations?  If so, you might try `Throttle` (called `debounce` in RxJs) or `Sample` instead.